# Xcode 5 iOS 7 Game Development add main menu at launch

Tags: ios7, xcode5

Okay so I am very new to IOS Development and I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction for implementing a main menu into a game! I am using Sprite kit for my game and I would like a good tutorial or reference to add main menus! :)